# Powershell Save off attachments in Subfolders in Outlook

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

A little background first.

In my Inbox I have a Subfolder called One
Inside this is an email from someone with an attachment called One.pdf
In my Inbox I have a Subfolder called Two
Inside this is an email from someone with an attachment called Two.pdf
In my Inbox I have a Subfolder called Own inside this I have a Subfolder called Three.
Inside this is an email from someone with an attachment called Three.pdf
In my Inbox I have am Email with an attachment called Four.pdf

```
Inbox
-----One
--------Three
-----Two
```

Still with me? :)

I have a requirement to do the following.

I need to parse through the inbox and find the .PDF attachment and save it to another location on a drive. 
Then I need to parse through the Subfolders of the inbox. If I find a .pdf I need to do two things.

I need to check if the folders exists and if not create it. 
I need to then save the .PDF in that Subfolder to the folder I just created.

Currently I can create the Subfolders.

My problem is I am unable to create the correct files in each sub folder. Infact right now am only able to create four.pdf and I can create that in every sub folder.

Currently I am working with this code.

```
$O=0
$Obj = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$Name = $Obj.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)
$Mail = $Name.pickfolder()
$Path = "C:\Attached\"

$SubFolder = {
    param(
        $currentFolder
    )
foreach ($item in $currentFolder.Folders) {
 $Mail.Items | ForEach {
     $O=$O+1
     $_.Attachments | foreach {
         $item.FolderPath 
       & $SubFolder $item
        }
    } 
}
}


$Walk = & $SubFolder $Mail

ForEach ($Fo in $Walk){
    $Fo.Items | ForEach {
    $O=$O+1
    $_.Attachments | foreach  {
    $Sub = $Fo
    $Pos = $Sub.IndexOf("\")
    $LeftPart = $Sub.Substring($Pos+28)
    $FilePath = $Path + $LeftPart + "\"

    If ($_.filename -like "*.PDF") {
    $_
        If (!(Test-Path -path $FilePath))
            {
            $Dest = New-Item $FilePath -type directory 
            }
            $_.saveasfile((Join-Path  $FilePath $_.filename))
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This allows the selection of the Outlook folder and then does nothing. If I change $Fo.Items to $Mail.items it creates the folders and the four.pdf

I know $Fo isn't what I want it to be but am not sure what differection to take from here.

Any advice please. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I was voted down, be intrested to know?

Anyway. I can to this solution for my issue.

Each "section" will drill down a sub folder level, build the folder structure then save off the attahments based on type. Its by no means pretty but it does the job I need. I have posted it here for reference.

```
$O=0
$Outlook = New-Object -com "Outlook.Application"
$NameSpace = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$Mail = $NameSpace.pickfolder()
$Parent = $Mail.Folders
$Path = “C:\Attached\”


ForEach ($Folder in $Parent) {
#Parent Folder.
ForEach($SubFolder in $Folder) {
#First subfolder. 
  ForEach ($Item in $SubFolder.Items){
    $O=$O+1
    $Sub = $SubFolder.FolderPath
    $LeftPart = $Sub.Substring($Pos+28)
    $FilePath = $Path + $LeftPart + "\"
     If (!(Test-Path -path $FilePath))
            {
            $Dest = New-Item $FilePath -type directory 
            }

    foreach ($Attach in $Item.Attachments){
        If ($Attach.filename -like "*.PDF") {
            $Attach.saveasfile((Join-Path  $FilePath $Attach.filename))
            }
    If ($Attach.filename -like "*.doc*") {
            $Attach.saveasfile((Join-Path  $FilePath $Attach.filename))
            }
        }
    }
    ForEach ($SubSubFolder in $SubFolder.Folders){
    #Second Subfolder.
        ForEach ($SubItem in $SubSubFolder.Items){
        $1=$1+1
        $Sub = $SubSubFolder.FolderPath
        $LeftPart = $Sub.Substring($Pos+28)
        $FilePath = $Path + $LeftPart + "\"
         If (!(Test-Path -path $FilePath))
                {
                $Dest = New-Item $FilePath -type directory 
                }

        foreach ($Attach in $SubItem.Attachments){
        If ($Attach.filename -like "*.PDF") {
                $Attach.saveasfile((Join-Path  $FilePath $Attach.filename))
                }
        If ($Attach.filename -like "*.doc*") {
                $Attach.saveasfile((Join-Path  $FilePath       $Attach.filename))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```